# What actually happens when animating bounds origin of a view controller's view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

If I animate the bounds origin of a view controller's view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.view.bounds.origin.y = 20
}
```

all of its subviews animate upward by 20 points. But I thought I just moved the bounds origin down 20 points, so why don't the subviews move downward by 20? What is actually happening when I perform this animation?

Or is it simply that in the bounds coordinate system, positive is upward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be confusing the `bounds` of a view with the `frame` of a view.

> But I thought I just moved the bounds origin down 20 points, so why don't the subviews move downward by 20?

No, if you moved the `frame` (where this view is located in its superview’s coordinate system) down 20, then it (and its subviews) would go down 20. But you adjusted the `bounds`, not the `frame`.

> What is actually happening when I perform this animation?

To make it a little easier to see, I’ll give the view in question its own background color so you can see the view with respect to its subviews. Below, I shifted the bounds by 50 points. By changing the `origin` of the `bounds` from 0, 0 to 0, 50, we’re saying “the top left corner of this view’s own coordinate system is no longer 0, 0, but rather is 0, 50”, thereby shifting all of its subviews up 50:

[image]

Comment: What confused me was that in the frame's context, up is negative, while in the bounds' context, up is positive. I assumed that `(0,0)` was a universal point (of the window, perhaps) on a universal coordinate system and that anything that traveled up and/or left from that point (frame or bounds) was entering negative territory. Thanks for the explanation!